# Javascript is not working after clicking outside of modal window on bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

After clicking outside the modal window, then open again the same modal window. All the functionality I had inside just stopped working.

I don't want to prevent the user from clicking outside the modal, any idea on what i can do to avoid this problem?

I have the following line of code for calling the modal window:

```
<a href="/samples/edit/{{$sample->project_id}}/{{$sample->id}}" data-target="#editSample" data-toggle="modal"> {{$sample->name}}</a>
```

And here I have some javascript code that is executed inside the modal.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

$("input[name$='data_input']").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log('test');
    var type = $(this).val();
    $("#data_input_type").val(type);

    $("div.data_input").hide();
    $("#data" + type).show();

    var btn = event.target.id;
    if (btn === 'toggle-xyz')
    {
        $('#sample-btn-xyz').addClass('active');
        $('#sample-btn-drillhole').removeClass('active');
    }
    else
    {
        $('#sample-btn-drillhole').addClass('active');
        $('#sample-btn-xyz').removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

now when the user clicks outside the modal window to close it, and if the user decides to open the window again. all the Javascript stops working. I have to refresh the page in order to open again the modal and be able to work with all the functionality inside the modal

Comment: You need to add more detail to your question.

Comment: Welcome (?!) to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. Strangely enough you seem to have plenty rep so should know better than to ask without any code or details

Comment: Are you using Ruby on Rails, or what?

Comment: just php and javascript

Comment: If my answer below doesn't help, please post a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)!

Answer (score 0):

At a guess (given the amount of code you've given) I wonder if the click events are becoming detached.

Instead of `$(element).click(function(){});`

... use jQuery's [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method like this:

`$(element).on('click',function(){});`

Answer (score 0):

So what I did, was that I added a refresh on the page every time the modal window was being closed by clicking outside of it. Still wondering if there is a better solution. But so far this is working.

```
window.location.reload()
```